# Как положить результат работы функции в глобальную переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var resultVal;

var newObj = {
    item0: '0000',
    item1: '0001',
    item2: '0002',
    item3: '0003',
    item4: '0004',
    item5: '0005'
};

var indexToFind = ['item1', 'item3', 'item5'];

$.each(newObj, function(index, value) {

        if ( indexToFind.indexOf(index) != -1 ) {
        resultVal = value;

        }

        console.log(resultVal);

});

console.log(resultVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Почему когда я хочу посмотреть значения из переменной resultVal вне теле функции мне выводит только 1 значение? А когда я смотрю значения в теле функции все значения видны ? Вопрос собственно в том как все нужные мне значения сохранить в глобальную переменную ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов:

**"="** - Это присвоение значения к переменной.

**"+"** - Это сложение.

Можно сделать вот так: "`x = x + y`" тоже самое упрощенно получится: "`x += y`"

Наглядно будет так, *по циклу:*

```
x = "";   Y = "0001", Y = "0003", Y = "0005" //Присвоение переменой Y значения из массива по циклу.

x += y;
X = "" + "0001\n" + "0003\n" + "0005\n"
result: 
      001
      003
      005
```

```js
var resultVal ="";

var newObj = {
    item0: '0000',
    item1: '0001',
    item2: '0002',
    item3: '0003',
    item4: '0004',
    item5: '0005'
};

var indexToFind = ['item1', 'item3', 'item5'];

$.each(newObj, function(index, value) {

        if ( indexToFind.indexOf(index) != -1 ) {
          resultVal += value+ "\n";
        }           
       //console.log(resultVal);
});

console.log(resultVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! а можете пояснить вот этот момент resultVal += value+ почему и плюс и равно стоит ?

Comment: Понял, спасибо. У меня кстати в консоли вот так вот выдает undefined0001 0003 0005, от куда взялся undefined ?

Comment: @Mistio Вы написали `var resultVal;` вместо `var resultVal ="";`.

Comment: Забыл resultVal = '';  кавычки дописать...  Как я понял все значения сливаются в одно ? Все равно, чтоб удобно было работать с этими значениями надо их в массив преобразовывать, верно?

Comment: Да, если нужно работать с ними в дальнейшем то в массив, данный вариант больше подходит для строковых значений.

Comment: Ну и что? У нас же мощные компьютеры, пусть работают - сначала объекты в строку, потом строку в массив.

Comment: Понял! буду учится дальше, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Вы каждый раз присваиваете переменной `resultVal` другое значение. Конечно она не будет помнить, чему была равна до этого. Если Вам надо собрать набор значений, используйте массив:

```js
var resultVal = [];

var newObj = {
    item0: '0000',
    item1: '0001',
    item2: '0002',
    item3: '0003',
    item4: '0004',
    item5: '0005'
};

var indexToFind = ['item1', 'item3', 'item5'];

$.each(newObj, function(index, value) {

    if ( indexToFind.indexOf(index) != -1 ) {
        resultVal.push(value);
    }

});

console.log(resultVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо! ясно, надо методы подучить...

Comment: @Mistio Еще раз хотел бы обратить Ваше внимание на значок "галочка" слева от ответа.

Comment: А понял, я тут просто впервые.